# XML text extraction

Tags: java, xml, xpath

**Scenario:**

Given the following XML file:

```
<a:root
xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">

<h:table>
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

<f:table>
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa

</a:root>
```

How do I extract the text inside the main element `<a:root>`:

```
"\naaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n"
```

The code I have right now is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Stack;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


public class Proof {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = null;
        DocumentBuilder docBuild = null;
        try {

            dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            docBuild = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = docBuild.parse(new File("test2.xml"));

            System.out.println(doc.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But it returns the text I desire ("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa") + the inner text for the rest of the elements . Output:

```
    Apples
    Bananas




  African Coffee Table
  80
  120


aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

The requirement is **not** to use an additional XML java library !

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a correct, short and simple XPath one-liner expression that selects exactly the wanted text node. :)

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, I think you need to reduce self-importance. At this moment I can't provide Java code, but I provide C# code and, as I know, you is not only XML guru, but also .NET-guru ;-), so you can check result: `var result = doc.SelectNodes(@"a:root/text()", xmlnsManager).OfType<XmlText>();`. Result should be `\r\n\raaaaaaaaaaaaaa\r\n\r\n`... :-)

Comment: @Kirill Polishchuk: Run your code with Saxon or AltovaXML and count the number of text nodes -- your code produces -- by shere luck --  expected results only with some (microsoft) XSLT processors, because their default settings are to strip-off whitespace-only text nodes. Here we speak not about "self-importance", but about the (lack of) basic knowledge.

Comment: @Dimitre, I don't say that you're wrong, but on the contrary you're 100% correct. But, as I dimly remember, Java parser produces the same result. Therefore, I wrote that your solution is overkill. Anyway, OP will accept appropriate answer. Nothing personal. :-)

Comment: @Kirill Polishchuk: To give the readers precise knowledge is more important than whether I or You are wrong. In this case you obstinately support a wrong statement. With this you show that you are unable to learn from your mistakes and from the knowledge provided by others. This is a very useful,  *good to know* fact about yourself and readers should take this into account when reading any answer provided by you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The answer by @Kirill Polishchuk is not corect**:

The proposed:

```
a:root/text()
```

1. **Is a relative expression** and if it isn't evaluated having the root (`/`) node as the context node it selects nothing in the provided XML document.
2. **Even the XPath expression: `/a:root/text()` is incorrect**, because it selects three text nodes -- all text node children of the top element -- including two whitespace-only text nodes.

**Here is a correct XPath solution**:

```
/a:root/text()[string-length(normalize-space()) > 0]
```

**When this Xpath expression is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<a:root
xmlns:a="UNDEFINED !!!!"
xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">

<h:table>
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

<f:table>
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa

</a:root>
```

It selects the last (and only non-whitespace-only) text node child of the top element, as required:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:a="UNDEFINED !!!!"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "/a:root/text()
           [string-length(normalize-space()) > 0]"/>"

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied against the provided XML document (above), the wanted, correctly selecte text node is output**:

```
"

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa

"
```

Comment: Overkill. `a:root/text()` will select exactly 1 text-node (2 whitespace-only text nodes will be igneored).

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath: `a:root/text()`

Comment: There are at least two problems with this XPath expression that prevent it from selecting exactly the text node wanted by the OP -- see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Stack;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


public class Proof {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = null;
    DocumentBuilder docBuild = null;
    try {

        dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docBuild = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = docBuild.parse(new File("test2.xml"));

         Element x= doc.getDocumentElement();
       NodeList m=x.getChildNodes();
       for(int i=0;i<m.getLength();i++){
           Node it=m.item(i);
           if(it.getNodeType()==3){
               System.out.println(it.getNodeValue());
           }
       }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}