# How to combine XML via node attributes Java

Tags: java, regex, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML example:

```
<Template>
   <Text id="1">You don't qualify because</Text>
   <PertinentDataInputNodeNameListInline id="2">ApplicableConditions</PertinentDataInputNodeNameListInline>
   <Text id="3">.</Text>
</Template>
```

Note: this is just an example, there could be more than 3 children nodes of Template. The way we know there sentence is to be combined is via the id attribute.

How can I combine this (using regex or the most efficient approach) to construct a sentence perhaps using it's attributes in the following manner: id1+id2+id3+...+idn. So output should be:

> You don't qualify becauseApplicableConditions.

Notice the attribute id for every child of Template node. Any help or assistance would be much appreciate.

**Edit:**

Removed code because it's distracting from my actual question.

Comment: Where is the code you've made?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292857/xml-text-extraction

Comment: Never parse XML with regular expressions. There are XML parsers for that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Regex, it's much better to just use a stripping tag function. This is actually dead simple with [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org).

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```